# Custom library compiles fine, but fails with undefined refences when linked against

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking, crypto++

I'm currently building a library using cmake and crypto++. While the library compiles just fine the code referencing it does not.

cmake for library:

```
add_library(MYCrypto Crypto.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MYCrypto libcrypto++.a)
set_target_properties(MYCrypto PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "includes/MYCrypto.hpp")
install(TARGETS File MYCrypto ARCHIVE DESTINATION ~/.local/dev-bin/bin PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ~/.local/dev-bin/includes)
```

MYCrypto.hpp

```
#ifndef MYCrypto
#define MYCrypto
#include <string>
namespace MYCrypto
{
    std::string hashSha256(std::string);
    std::string hashMd5(std::string);
}
#endif
```

Crypto.cpp

```
#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1
#include <cryptopp/iterhash.h>
#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/md5.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "MYCrypto.hpp"

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
string encrypt(string data, T hasher)
{
    stringstream output;
    CryptoPP::byte* digest;

    hasher.Update((const CryptoPP::byte*)data.c_str(),data.size());
    digest = new CryptoPP::byte[hasher.DigestSize()];
    hasher.Final(digest);

    for (int i=0; i < hasher.DigestSize(); i++) output << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)digest[i];
    delete[] digest;

    return output.str();
}

string MYCrypto::hashSha256(string data)
{
    return encrypt(data, CryptoPP::SHA256());
}

string MYCrypto::hashMd5(string data)
{
    return encrypt(data, CryptoPP::Weak1::MD5());
}
```

CMake for consuming application

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(TEST VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)

include_directories(~/.local/dev-bin/includes)
link_directories(~/.local/dev-bin/bin)

add_library(Archive Archive.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Archive MYCrypto)
```

Archive.hpp

```
#ifndef Archive
#define Archive
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
namespace Archive
{
   std::string getImportPath(std::string);
   bool fileExistsInDatabase(std::string, std::string);
}
#endif
```

archive.cpp

```
#include "MYCrypto.hpp"
#include "Archive.hpp"

using namespace std;

string Archive::getImportPath(string path)
{
    return MYCrypto::hashSha256(Path);
}
```

when i try to compile my second cmake progject i get errors like this

```
[build] /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/.local/dev-bin/bin/libMYCrypto.a(Crypto.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E[_ZTVN8CryptoPP5Weak13MD5E]+0x38): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::IteratedHashBase<unsigned int, CryptoPP::HashTransformation>::Update(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)'
```

I don't understand how to fix this error. I linked statically so this second project should only know about the functions declared on the public header file and i should no longer require crypto++.

How do i make this second project compile?

Comment: `encrypt` is declared in namespace `MYCrypto` and then there is a definition of `encrypt` in the global namespace.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
I'm afraid i dont see what you're talking about. ```encrypt``` is not defined anywhere in MYCrypto.hpp where the namespace is declared. I only ever declared ```encrypt``` globally. Does it need to be put into the MYCrypto namespace to be seen?

Comment: oh sorry misread

Comment: are you linking cryptopp? in the second project i mean.
cryptopp isn't a header-only library, so you need to link it even on the second project.
your first project will not contain nothing about cryptopp code (except inline code). 
the two projects must use the same version of cryptopp obv or you will see the hell

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper
no i do not link cryptopp in the second project. Nor do i want to. I want to compile the library into one big binary so that i dont have to be dependent on outside files. Is this possible? I thought that's what static linking did.

Comment: Static linking makes sense only for applications. There is "one definition rule" in the language and if you link `liba` and `libb` libraries both defining `foo` (even it is the same and defined via transitional dependency) you still should get multiple definition warning from the linker - no symbol isolation is usually provided (DLLs on Windows require to fully resolve all dependencies but not on Linux and static libraries are just an archive of object files). Usually there are linker-specific ways to force merge the static libs but it will cause troubles is the library linked multiple times.

Comment: @dewaffled
So if i'm understanding this correctly, i have to link crypto++ to every project that consumes MYCrypto, however the finished executable will not need libcryptopp.a to function when it's given to an end user?

Comment: Yes. Also, you can [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets) your library via cmake and it will link dependencies automatically when consumed e.g via `find_package`.

Comment: @dewaffled
please submit an answer so i may accept. it was very hard to search for this. I think it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static linking is well defined only for applications not for the libraries.

There is "one definition rule" in the language and it applies to the executable as whole. If you link `liba` and `libb` libraries both providing `foo` (even it is the same and defined via transitional dependency) you most likely will get multiple definition warning from the linker - no symbol isolation is usually provided. There are platform-specific exceptions: DLLs on Windows require to fully resolve and link all dependencies and export only explicitly exported symbols but this is not the case e.g. for shared libraries on Linux, and static libraries are just an archive of object files and cannot link anything on all major platforms.

So, you link static libraries to the executable, not to the other static libraries.

Usually there are linker-specific ways to force merge the static libraries but again it will cause troubles is the library symbols get linked multiple times.

But if you have

```
target_link_libraries(MYCrypto libcrypto++.a)
...
target_link_libraries(Application MyCrypto)
```

in a single cmake file, it can see the dependencies and will link the dependecies automatically itself.

If you want to distribute the library separately and want to simplify its usage you can [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets) it via cmake and if the executable is also built with cmake then the users can import your library with `find_package` that will link the requried dependencies.